# How can I set Forti VPN so that http/https are not using VPN Xubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, vpn, https, fortinet

I need to browse (ie, HTTP/HTTPS) and at the same time connected to remote network via VPN (for ssh, which works fine). Maybe my HTTP/HTTPS request are sent till remote VPN network and then got blocked there.

So, is there any way to set my PC not to send HTTP/HTTPS requests over VPN? I am looking for a setting/commands which enables me to route these requests here itself.

I am using openFortiGUI (which says, PPP+SSL VPN tunnel) on Xubuntu machine.

Comment: Is there any ssh command equivalent to replace openFortiGUI and restrict the VPN for a  particular ssh session?

Answer (score 0):

#### I have got a workarround with the help of SOCKv5 tunnel (Ubuntu + Firefox).

*I shall close this issue with following info (which could help others facing similar issue):*

1. The command needed for creating SOCKv5 using ssh:
   **ssh -N -D 9090 username@192.168.XXX.YYY**
   (here 9090 can be any unused socket port number)
2. The above command will create a SOCKv5 tunnel which tunnels various protocols between computer you are running the command and the specified IP 192.168.XXX.YYY (doesn't matter it's in local network or in VPN).
3. Go to Firefox and type "about:preferences" in the url.
4. Under "Network Settings" open settings, select the radio-button "Manual proxy configuration".
5. Under "SOCKS Host" text box type "127.0.0.1" and under "Port" text box type "9090" (the same port number set in ssh command above).
6. Further you can add "No proxy for" text box as required. That is, if you need any .com HTTP/HTTPS request need not enter VPN you may add those under "No proxy for" text box.
7. Click "OK" to save this settings.

**How does ssh tunnel solves, the Firewall block I am facing?**

Usually VPN service provider will allow SSH connection, but not the HTTP/HTTPS requests (which is in my case they are allowing ssh connection). So using SSH tunnel, I made the HTTP/HTTPS requests to stay hidden from the organization's Firewall. Of course there is a need of known system IP (192.168.XXX.YYY) username and password present (with in the VPN, in case the HTTP/HTTPS request are organization specific) which has access to HTTP/HTPPS requests. This setting makes the HTTP/HTTPS request, go all the way from my system to VPN (under ssh tunnel) and then open up as HTTP/HTTPS request as if they are originated from the system 192.168.XXX.YYY instead (and get served).

If you are not at all interested in passing the HTTP/HTTPS requests via VPN, then use the "No Proxy for" option which is better option for me. Well this applies for all the HTTP/HTTPS whose requests are served even outside the organization (example: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)).

*Reference:*

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-socks-tunnel-for-private-browsing/
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/
(you can find similar solution for Windows OS using Putty application)